# How to get the first cell in the active row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I want my Google Apps Script app get the current selected row in a spreadsheet, I use something like this:

```
function getCurrentRow() {
  var currentRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
  return currentRow;
}
```

But what if I want to get the first cell in this row (to put a comment in it), how do I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `offset` to get a range relative to the active range.

```
function getFirstCellInRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var firstCell = activeCell.offset(0, 1-activeCell.getColumn());
  return firstCell;
}
```

Or just use `getRange(A1notation)`, starting with what you had:

```
function getFirstCellInRow2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currentRow = sheet.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
  return sheet.getRange("A"+currentRow);
}
```

To write into the first cell in the row:

```
getFirstCellInRow().setValue('Tada');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `getCell()` method you can use  ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer) )

```
function getFirstCell() {
  var firstCell= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection().getCell(1,1);
  return firstCell;
}
```

Comment: `getCell` operates relative to the range, so it won't return the first cell in the row, but the top-left cell in the active range.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will insert "My Info" in the first row available in column A.

```
function FirstCellColumnA() {
  // replace with destination ID
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetID');

  // replace with destination Sheet tab name
  var ss = s.getSheetByName('sheetname');

  // In Column A first ROW Available ss.getLastRow()+1 = find the
  // first row available, 1 = start in column 1, 1 = rows to start,
  // 1 = column where to put the data.
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 1).setValue('My Info');
}
```

I hope this help you.